# Not able to read value from json object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

**Problem Statement:** Need to check if value present in json record and if yes, return true as output as variable using Python 3.x

**The code that I am trying to use:**

```
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
outputdata = data.decode("utf-8")
outputdata1 = json.loads(outputdata)
for key,value in outputdata1.items():
  print(key, value)
```

**Output I get:**

```
next_page_token None
items [{'name': 'pythontest34', 'id': '0126ffc8-5656-423e-b7fe-56d4e93a80d6', 'created_at': '2022-06-16T04:37:32.958Z'}, {'name': 'avengers', 'id': '41541893-f916-426b-b135-c75898759b0b3', 'created_at': '2022-06-24T08:39:39.806Z'}, {'name': 'abkalkib217', 'id': '4cc606f1-749f-4e5d-9d76-41460dc9a578', 'created_at': '2022-06-24T15:11:17.145Z'}, {'name': 'Common', 'id': '7bf46575-f02a-44fc-8b65-d596d8f1ba30', 'created_at': '2022-06-21T06:11:11.102Z'}, {'name': 'ParameterTest', 'id': 'c4eff567-a6af-4a7f-b907-60ae98d4925a', 'created_at': '2022-06-01T09:55:04.944Z'}, {'name': 'ab-synpase', 'id': 'c9655981-70f8-43d8-ba8e-7f16395ef969', 'created_at': '2022-05-18T18:24:04.526Z'}]
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

If I pass `name` as python runtime argument(`sys.argv`) it should return "True" if this value in above output

How to get into `items` and get this name based on runtime parameter

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you mean a command line argument with "runtime parameter", you can use the `argparse` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html; for looking inside `items`, you can use `outputdata1['items']` which should refer to the list of entries with `name`, `id`, etc.

Comment: Ok now with `outputdata1['items']` I get list of entries in name and id, how to put a filter condition on this to get one particular name ?

Comment: I tried with for `for key,value in outputdata1['items']: print(key, value)` and get me `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: @asp Try: ```for itm in outputdata1['items']: for key, value in itm.items(): print(key, value)```. outputdata1['items'] is a list containing dicts. the .items() method of dicts will give you the key, value you are looking for.

Comment: @XingzhouLiu now I get key values correctly, but any way to filter out to `print True if  value = avengers present` in above output for example

Comment: `for token in outputdata1['items']: if token['name'] == 'avengers': print(token)` would print out the token that has a name field with the value `avengers`. You're iterating over a list of dictionaries, and each key in the dictionary can be accessed through `token['fieldname']`.

Comment: @asp, ```output = [] for itm in outputdata1['items']:  dnew = {} for key, value in itm.items(): if not value == 'avengers' : dnew[key] = value``` then ``` output.append(dnew)``` in the outer loop. There is a list comprehension way to do it, but from an execution standpoint the more complex syntax does the same thing. You can't remove items from a dict while you are iterating over it, so you have to create a new instance of it and copy over only what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have parsed data using json.loads() which returns results as Python dictionary. check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

I have added sample json data and one of the way to navigating json data structure and filter data based on field or it's value.

```
test_array = '[{"id": 1, "date": "2021-06-01T12:45:30.9861524-04:00", "temperatureC": 39, "temperatureF": 102, "summary": "Sweltering"}, {"id":2, "date": "2021-06-02T12:45:30.9861607-04:00", "temperatureC": -12, "temperatureF": 11, "summary": "Scorching"}, {"id":3,"date": "2021-06-03T12:45:30.9861613-04:00", "temperatureC": 50, "temperatureF": 121, "summary": "Chilly"}, {"id":4,"date": "2021-06-04T12:45:30.9861617-04:00", "temperatureC": 51, "temperatureF": 123, "summary": "Chilly"},{"id":5,"date": "2021-06-05T12:45:30.9861647-04:00", "temperatureC": 3, "temperatureF": 37, "summary": "Hot"}]'

test_array_to_json = json.loads(test_array)

for item in test_array_to_json:
    print('data row:',item)
    for itemkey in item.keys():
        print('data column key:',itemkey,'data column value:',item[itemkey])
        #If you wan to filter on field only
        if itemkey == "summary" :
            print('filtered data key',itemkey, 'filtered data value',item[itemkey])
        #If you want to filter on field and it's value    
        if (itemkey == "summary" and item[itemkey] =="Chilly") :
            print('filtered data key',itemkey, 'filtered data value',item[itemkey])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all suggestions.. @MatsLindh @Xingzhou Liu @Chinmay T
the following worked. I was figuring out how to return false if value does not exist for a given key. Unless I declare variable(status) a default value "False" it was returning empty value. I need to consume this true or false in next workflow job.

```
  status = "False"
    outputdata1 = json.loads(outputdata)
    for token in outputdata1['items']:
        for key, value in token.items():
            #print(key,value)
            if value == "avengers":
                status = "True"
   print(status)
```